# First time homebrewing, odd film in jug (not on top of beer)

Tags: beer, brewing, ipa

Here's a picture of what I'm talking about.[image: Odd film at top]

So for reference, I got the Everyday IPA kit from Brooklyn Brew Shop for christmas, and I just got around to using it last week. This is day 4 of the fermentation period, and I just switched the airlock on in place of the blowoff tube.

After the heavy bubbling from the first few days of fermentation, theres this weird film at the top of the jug. Can anyone tell me what this is and if it's bad?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Are you referring to the cream colored gunk on the top (above the beer level)? If so, it is yeast, proteins and a few other things that got stuck to the side during krauzening.

Almost all beers do this and it is not a problem.

Enjoy the beer, I got the same kit a few years ago! :)

Answer (score 1):

You say "not on top of beer"

Anyways the cream color on top and bottom are normal and signs of a good fermentation. On top is what dried to the bottle after the krauesen fell back in, the bottom is much the same mostly yeast trub.

Enjoy the beer looks to be doing well.